# How to put files in a folder and generate .zip file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, zip, compression

I want to generate a .zip file which contains some files and folders. The file inside the folder might be contained in some other paths and I want to put files in another folder and generate a .zip file from them.

By other words, I don't want to physically generate the folder with files. The files might be on some roots and I want to generate folder virtually to put them on the .zip file.

```
Imports System.IO.Compression    
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("source","destination.zip",CompressionLevel.Optimal,False)
```

As an example if I have these files on my website:

```
- ~/files/image/1.jpg
- ~/files/pdf/2.pdf
- ~/intro.docx
```

I want to put them on a zip which when I extract it, the files will be as follows:

```
- ~/files/1.jpg
- ~/files/2.pdf
- ~/intro.docx
```

Comment: Since you want to remove some parts of a path for some files, you should explain what logic governs the removal of such parts. In any case, you cannot use the `CreateFromDirectory` method anymore. You'll have to build your own list of modified paths.

Answer (score 0):

For the source put the root folder and it will do it
example :
 This is yours

```
- ~/files/image/1.jpg
- ~/files/pdf/2.pdf
- ~/intro.docx
```

But before this there is a root folder whic is the `~` just simpily put as a source

Comment: How to add the files into the srouce?

Comment: The source is a folder not files you can do 1 files or 1 folder compresion you cannot make 3 files the only 1 think is coming to my mind now that you create a folder programaticly and copy the files into this then compress it then you delet the folder